# Como diferenciar botões de uma ListView?

Tags: android

Tenho uma `ListView` com `ImageButton`s em cada linha, e quero que quando eu clicar no botão ele salve o produto com o preço, para eu adicionar em uma activity. Como faço para pegar as informações da linha do botão clicado?

[image: Uma tela com uma lista de linhas, onde cada linha tem um produto com um preço diferente e o mesmo ícone de carrinho de compras na frente]

Comment: Mas qual é a dúvida?

Comment: como eu posso contar esses buttons, ja que ele cria o button conforme uma string é adicionada

Comment: Mas o que tem a ver contar os botões com salvar o produto com o preço?

Comment: se eu clicar no botão, ele vai salvar o produto e o preço, como faço isso, desculpe se não estou conseguindo me expressar

Comment: Tudo bem. Editei sua pergunta retirando as informações não relacionadas à dúvida. Lembre-se de falar apenas o que for relevante para sua pergunta não ficar grande demais. Além disso, quando alguém pedir esclarecimentos nos comentários, lembre-se que você mesmo pode (e deve!) editar sua pergunta com os detalhes em vez de apenas colocá-los nos comentários. Outra dica: coloque descrições nas imagens, senão sua pergunta fica invisível para usuários de leitores de tela. Dê uma olhada em como eu fiz caso queira uma ideia de como se faz. No mais, seja bem-vindo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode associar um listener ligeiramente diferente pra cada um desses botões direto no Adapter. Seu `getView` ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View linha = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_de_produto, parent,
                        false);
    ImageButton carrinhoButton = (ImageButton)  linha.findViewById(R.id.carrinhoButton);
    carrinhoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               // Aqui entra o código que vai usar a variável position para fazer uma coisa diferente pra cada caso.
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: sim, era bem isso que eu queria. desculpa por me enrolar na pergunta